# PPS GPIO with Buildroot image on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: linux, udev, buildroot, device-tree

I using Buildroot trying to build a Linux image for the Raspberry Pi 3 in which I have access to pulse-per-second (PPS) inputs on one of the GPIO pins.

First off, I have tried this with the standard Raspbian distribution and got it to work with the following changes:

- Add `dtoverlay=pps-gpio,gpiopin=20` to `/boot/config.txt`.
- Add `pps-gpio` to `/etc/modules`.

I then get an entry `/dev/pps0` and when connecting a wire with PPS signal to physical pin 38 on the RPi3 and running `pps-test /dev/pps0` I get the expected one signal per second.
So far so good.

Now I would like to recreate this with my own image built with Buildroot. I'm using the default `configs/raspberrypi3_64_defconfig` configuration, but with the following changes in `make nconfig`:

- Using kernel branch `rpi-4.14.y-rt` from `github.com/raspberrypi/linux`
- `systemd` as init system
- `/dev management using udev (from systemd)`
- `Target packages` -> `Hardware handling` -> `pps-tools` activated

(I think that is all the changes I made, but I might have forgotten something..)

In the `sdcard.img` which I get as output I see the file `pps-gpio.dtbo` in the boot partition. I add the line `dtoverlay=pps-gpio,gpiopin=20` to the file `config.txt`. I also add the line `pps-gpio` to a file named `pps.conf` which I put in `/etc/modules-load.d` on the file system.

When I boot the system I get no entry `/dev/ppsX` but when I run `lsmod` I get (among others):

`pps_gpio               16384  0
pps_core               20480  1 pps_gpio`

Does this mean the `dtoverlay` has been correctly loaded? What can I try in order to get an entry in `/dev/ppsX`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out what was missing was to in `make nconfig` also select:

- `Kernel` -> `Build Device Tree with overlay support`

Also, in the file `<buildroot>/board/raspberrypi3-64/genimage-raspberrypi3-64.cfg` add the `pps-gpio.dtbo` file so that the `image boot.vfat` section looks like this:

```
image boot.vfat {
  vfat {
    files = {
      "bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb",
      "bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb",
      "bcm2837-rpi-3-b.dtb",
      "rpi-firmware/bootcode.bin",
      "rpi-firmware/cmdline.txt",
      "rpi-firmware/config.txt",
      "rpi-firmware/fixup.dat",
      "rpi-firmware/start.elf",
      "Image"
    }

    file overlays/pps-gpio.dtbo {
      image = "rpi-firmware/overlays/pps-gpio.dtbo"
    }
  }
  size = 32M
}
```

Putting the `pps.conf` file under `etc/modules-load.d` is not necessary.

With these changes I get a `/dev/pps0` device automatically when booting the system.